# Drag a label from a view to a window in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement  a  feel like drag and drop of label in iPhone. I am able to drag and drop inside a single view. But if I try to to drag the label from my view to another view added on the window, the label goes below the second view (added to window). But I want to drag the label over the second view (added to window).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the label and your second view as subviews of window, make them both subviews of a view which you add to the window.  Within that view,

[self bringSubviewToFront: label];